# SparkSessionExtensions - Check fields coming from tables

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to check fields and files being accessed by Spark when people are loading data through the DataFrame API. Specifically so I can log something like the following:

```
"User A", "File1.csv", "cola, colb, colc"
"User A", "File2.csv", "cola, colb, colc"
```

I've been trying to do this using SparkSessionExtensions, but I've been struggling around finding documentation and examples on how to do this. Is there anything anyone could recommend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, solved it in the end. Needed to inject a custom optimizer rule and then intercept a LogicalRelationPlan, this gives the schema information. From there I can match the "relation" property and check if it's a HadoopFsRelation type, if so then I can extract the root paths and input files (amongst other things).

Now I just need to work out how to re-write the query as well